# User GETDATE() to put current date into SQL variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get the current date into a variable inside a SQL stored procedure using the following commands

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate as date
SET @LastChangeDate = SELECT GETDATE()
```

This gives me the following error: "Incorrect Syntax near 'SELECT'"

This is the first stored procedure I've ever written, so I'm unfamiliar with how variables work inside SQL.

Comment: What is the SQL dialect that you're using?

Comment: 7 questions, **no** accepted answers?

Comment: I just posted and I'm at work, where I'm interning.

Comment: @NealR - What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't need the `SELECT`

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate as date
SET @LastChangeDate = GetDate()
```

Comment: SET "AT"exportedDate = '20160427'
SET "AT"date1 = GETDATE(), "AT"exportedDate - 7 Month

Is it possible to sth like that as well?

Comment: SET "AT"date1 = DATEADD(Month, 1, "AT"exportedDate) just found out by trying

Answer (score 12):

Just use `GetDate()` not `Select GetDate()`

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate as date 
SET @LastChangeDate = GETDATE()
```

but if it's SQL Server,  you can also initialize in same step as declaration...

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate date = getDate()
```

Comment: Initializing in same step as declaration is 2008+?

Comment: I figured this out, pretty easy fix. Just get rid of the SELECT statement :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate as date 
SET @LastChangeDate = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @LastChangeDate = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for this.

According to [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the `ANSI SQL` euivalent to `GETDATE()`

```
DECLARE @LastChangeDate AS DATE;
SET @LastChangeDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```